# How does one prove Riemann's explicit formula?

Tags: number-theory, complex-analysis

Q: Is there a reference for a detailed proof of [Riemann's explicit formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formula) ?

I am reading the [TeXified version](http://www.claymath.org/millennium/Riemann_Hypothesis/1859_manuscript/EZeta.pdf) of Riemann's manuscript, but sometimes I can't follow (I think the author has kept typos from the [orignal paper](http://www.claymath.org/millennium/Riemann_Hypothesis/1859_manuscript/riemann1859.pdf)).

Here are some points I have trouble with (but there are others) :

- How does he calculate
  $$\int_{a+i\mathbb{R}} \frac{d}{ds} \left( \frac{1}{s} \log(1-s/\beta)\right) x^s ds$$
  on page 4 ?
- What do I need to know about [$Li(x)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) to see how the terms $Li(x^{1/2+i\alpha})$ appear ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend reading Edwards' excellent ['Riemann's Zeta Function'](http://books.google.com/books?id=ruVmGFPwNhQC&pg=PA1) (it's [cheap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486417409) !) since it details every part of Riemann's article (with more rigorous proofs of course !).

Concerning your second question see [page 27](http://books.google.com/books?id=ruVmGFPwNhQC&pg=PA27) of Edwards' book.
About the $\mathrm{Li}$ function you probably won't need more than Wikipedia's informations.
What is really required to understand Riemann's proof is a good knowledge of complex integration (the venerable [Whittaker and Watson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1603864547) may be useful for this).

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question in the title, not the body, Riemann's explicit formula is stated on page 244 of Stopple, A Primer of Analytic Number Theory, and discussed over the next several pages. By the way, it's considered that Riemann only gave a "heuristic proof," the first rigorous proof being given by von Mangoldt in 1895.